# Draw a Pie in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, graphics

I have drawn a arc in Objective C with the following code

```
    [newPath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle];
```

Now I want to draw two lines from center to both the ends of arc. How do I do that? One side I can draw with the following code:

```
    [newPath lineToPoint:center];
```

But how about the other side.

Comment: You use trigonometry to calculate the starting point of the arc, then `[newPath lineToPoint:startingPoint]` when the cursor is at the center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest (?) way do draw a pie is to use the fact that `appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:...` draws
a line from the current point to the starting point of the arc:

```
// Start at the center of the circle:
[newPath moveToPoint:center];
// This draws a line from the center to the starting point of the arc AND the arc:
[newPath appendBezierPathWithArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle];
// Closing the path draws a line from the end point of the arc back to the center:
[newPath closePath];
```

Comment: in iOS SDK equivalent method is addArcWithCenter:

Answer (score 0):

I have no chance to test it at this moment, but you can try something like this.

```
#import "math.h"

[newPath moveToPoint:center];
[newPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + radius * cos(endAngle * M_PI / 180),
                                    center.y + radius * sin(endAngle * M_PI / 180))];

[newPath moveToPoint:center];
[newPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(center.x + radius * cos(startAngle * M_PI / 180),
                                    center.y + radius * sin(startAngle * M_PI / 180))];
```